# The RLS field is required. What?

Tags: cartthrob

Brand new to CartThrob - trying to add the add-to-cart form using:

```
{exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form entry_id="{entry_id}" return="store/view_cart" quantity="1"}
    ${workshop_price}
    {title}
    <input type="submit" id="addToCart" class="btn-default" value="Add to cart" />
{/exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form}
```

And I get the error "**The RLS field is required.**". What's going wrong? I have the latest versions of both CT and EE.

Comment: And I should mention that I have added a channel with products, set the price field inside CartThrob for that channel and I'm calling the {exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form} inside a pair of {exp:channel:entries}.

Answer (score 2):

Actually turns out I already had a form tag above and below... that was causing the issue. Oops!